# Pandas pivot table and sort by multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort this table first by IN_FID ascending from top to bottom, and then by Jurisdiction, ascending from left to right. I was able to pivot the table and sort by IN_FID, but how do I add a second sort from left to right.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:my\path\myfile.csv')

df['Key']=df.groupby('IN_FID').cumcount()+1
s=df.pivot_table(index='IN_FID',columns='Key',values=['Jurisdiction','CURR_VOL'],aggfunc='first')
s=s.sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)                   

s.to_csv(r'C:\my\path\mynewfile.csv')
```

Where myfile.csv looks like this:

```
ROUTE_NAME  CURR_VOL    IN_FID  NEAR_RANK   Jurisdiction
test1       test1       1       test1       2
test1       test1       1       test1       3
test2       test2       2       test2       1
test3       test3       3       test3       2
test3       test3       3       test3       1
```

And mynewfile.csv would look like this:

```
IN_FID  CURR_VOL_1  Jurisdiction_1  CURR_VOL_2  Jurisdiction_2
1       test1       2               test1       3
2       test2       1       
3       test3       1               test3       2
```

Currently mynewfile.csv looks like this:

```
IN_FID  CURR_VOL_1  Jurisdiction_1  CURR_VOL_2  Jurisdiction_2
1       test1       2               test1       3
2       test2       1       
3       test3       2               test3       1
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include frames as text, not as images

Comment: Updated the tables.

Comment: In your expected output of `mynewfile.csv`, it looks like the last row's values are assigned to the wrong columns, which is different from sorting the columns by value. `Jurisdiction_1` currently shows `2`, but in the expected output, it would show `1`.

Comment: The column numbers in the names are arbitrary, so Jurisdiction_1 should just be the lowest value of Jurisdiction, Jurisdiction_2 should be the 2nd, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using `groupby` on `IN_FID` and then do `unstack()`.

```
df_new = df.sort_values(['IN_FID','Jurisdiction']) \
         .groupby('IN_FID')['CURR_VOL','Jurisdiction'] \
         .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values, columns['CURR_VOL','Jurisdiction'])) \
         .unstack().sort_index(1, level=1)

df_new.columns = df_new.columns.droplevel(1)
df_new.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Output looks like this

```
IN_FID  CURR_VOL    Jurisdiction    CURR_VOL    Jurisdiction
1       test1       2               test1       3
2       test2       1               None        None
3       test3       1               test3       2
```

Now you can use this `df_new` by renaming the columns as you like.